# Replace MergeFields in a Word 2003 document and keep style

Tags: c#, interop, ms-word, vsto, mergefield

I've been trying to create a library to replace the MergeFields on a Word 2003 document, everything works fine, except that I lose the style applied to the field when I replace it, is there a way to keep it?

This is the code I'm using to replace the fields:

```
private void FillFields2003(string template, Dictionary<string, string> values)
{
    object missing = Missing.Value;
    var application = new ApplicationClass();
    var document = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();

    try
    {
        // Open the file

        foreach (Field mergeField in document.Fields)
        {
            if (mergeField.Type == WdFieldType.wdFieldMergeField)
            {
                string fieldText = mergeField.Code.Text;
                string fieldName = Extensions.GetFieldName(fieldText);

                if (values.ContainsKey(fieldName))
                {
                    mergeField.Select();
                    application.Selection.TypeText(values[fieldName]);
                }
            }
        }
        document.Save();
    }
    finally
    {
        // Release resources
    }
}
```

I tried using the CopyFormat and PasteFormat methods in the selection, also using the get_style and set_style but to no exent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using TypeText over the top of your selection use the the Result property of the Field:

```
          if (values.ContainsKey(fieldName))
          {
             mergeField.Result = (values[fieldName]);
          }
```

This will ensure any formatting in the field is retained.

Comment: Hi

This helped a lot! thanks.
Although, the right format is:
   mergeField.Result.Text = (values[fieldName]).
Because the type of Result is "Range".

Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, f.Result.Text, as you say, absolutely.

Comment: Although it works, the result is not as intended. My code is `{MERGEFIELD ClientName * Upper}`. However, after running the merge, it doesn't display upper case of the client name. Can you help me? Thank you.

Comment: @ThangNguyen you might want to ask that as a new question. it's been a long time since i answered the above, and i'm not going to remember how it works in detail