# What namespace should I declare to use the Extension.GetFieldNames() method in C#?

Tags: c#, interop, ms-word, vsto, extension-methods

I was browsing quite a lot of threads recently and came across this one:

[Replace MergeFields in a Word 2003 document and keep style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525808/replace-mergefields-in-a-word-2003-document-and-keep-style-c?rq=1)

It's an old thread but looks very promising since I got the logic of the code down and am sure I will be able to utilize it. The only problem I am facing is that I can't seem to declare/use this method?

```
Extensions.GetFieldName()
```

Any ideas to substitute it though would also be appreciated! :)

Here is the actual code I am trying to use

```
foreach (Field mergeField in document.Fields)
{
   if (mergeField.Type == WdFieldType.wdFieldMergeField)
   {
      string fieldText = mergeField.Code.Text;
      string fieldName = Extensions.GetFieldName(fieldText);

      if (values.ContainsKey(fieldName))
      {
         mergeField.Select();
         application.Selection.TypeText(values[fieldName]);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: can you share a code sample? which namespaces are you already referencing? what is the error?

Comment: That's something the OP himself wrote. You will have to write your own

Comment: Actually there is no error.. It has that red wavy line underneath the Extensions "The name Extensions does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to get the fieldnames of the mergefields instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really dont think `Extensions.GetFieldName` is a inbuilt method.It could be user defined method and not present under interop.

Usually field names are retrieved like this

```
Int32 endMerge = fieldText.IndexOf("\\");
Int32 fieldNameLength = fieldText.Length - endMerge;
String fieldName = fieldText.Substring(11, endMerge - 11);
```

Please go through this [link](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/C_Sharp/Q_23967308.html).There is a very clear code on how to retieve the FieldNames.